# Installation & Varnish Test Results - Failed in 7.4 & 8.1 in magento marketplace

Tags: extensions, installation, varnish, magento2.4.3.p1, failed

[image]

Installation & Varnish Test Results - Failed in 7.4 & 8.1 when automation testing in marketplace

Answer (score 1):

Check your composer.json

```
"require": 
{ 
"php": "~7.4.0||~8.1.0","magento/framework": "~100.1|~101.0|~102.0|~103.0|~104.0"       
},
```

Than Check in your all page if you have [ cacheable="false" ] mention all block xml remove it or do in xml where template mention otherwise not.

Comment: Is this issue fix by adding above codes in composer.json ?

Comment: yes and you have to check [ cacheable=false ] from all phtml which is defined in block xml